# Parameterise the path C of a square

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a question,

I am required to parameterise the square with side lengths $a$, going in a counterclockwise direction.

I have determined then that the points are

$$(0,a),
(a,0),
(0,0),
(a,a)$$

Which are required to be parameterised independently andd then somehow combined, though I'm not 100% sure on how to do that

I then need to calculate the circulation by the equation $$ I = \oint_c F \cdot dr $$
Using the vector field $$ F = x^2y^3i + x^2y^3j $$

Which in this case I am unsure on what the C represents

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem might help, without parametrization, it'll be a simple double integral.

Comment: Unfortunately the question explicitly states not to use Stokes theorem, even though it will make things so much simpler. I guess they want us to know how to do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $C$ is unfortunate notation that hides the distinction between a path and its range.

One (of many suitable) parameterisations could be
$C:[0,4] \to \mathbb{R}^2$,
$C(t) = \begin{cases} (ta,0 ) , & t \in [0,1) \\
(a, (t-1)a) , & t \in [1,2) \\
(a-(t-2)a, a) , & t \in [2,3) \\
(0, a-(t-3)a) , & t \in [3,4]
\end{cases}$.

Then the integral is given by  $\int_0^4 \langle F(C(t)) C'(t) \rangle dt$.

Comment: oh thanks so much! I was thinking of using a piece wise function but I wasn't sure if it was able to be differentiated.

Comment: Well, I should really write it as the sum of integrals over $[k,k+1]$, but that would add to the clutter!

Comment: so i would take the integral of each segment? $$ \int^1_0 (ta,0) + \int^2_1 (a,t-1)a) ... $$

Comment: Well, $\int_0^1 F_x(C(t)) a dt + \int_2^2 F_y(C(t)) a dt + \cdots$. For example, for $t<1$, $C'(t) = (a,0)$.

Comment: That should have been $\int_1^2$, of course...

Comment: thanks so much for your help, it all makes sense now!